# Simulate mouse click on button in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I have button on website (not mine) and i need to click on it. 
Here's button's code

```
<button id="14874-subPoll-0-button-captcha-false" type="button" value="vote" class="vote captcha-prev-btn 14874">Vote</button>
```

I found this, but it doesn't work.

```
javascript:document.getElementById('#14874-subPoll-0-button-captcha-false').click();
```

Could you please tell me what's wrong?

Comment: Where do you place that code?

Comment: What is the `.click()` event supposed to do? Where exactly is that JS code found? Is it in a `<script>` tag or embedded somewhere (if so show us)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `getElementById` function is expecting an dom element id but you added the `#` in front of the id.  The `#` is required for JQuery selector but `document.getElementById` isn't part of JQuery.

Just remove the `#` from the id passed to the `getElementById` function.